# Disappearing polygons when zooming in Feature Cache extent

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql-server, zoom

I'm currently using ArcMap (v 10.6.1.) and an enterprise geodatabase (v 10.6.0) on SQL Server 2017.

I encountered a problem, when I build Feature Cache on full map extent and zoom in to my polygon feature. The polygon geometry is being cut and reduced, despite the fact that I do not use any of editing tools at that moment. Polygons are cut out of the shape of zoomed in extent (1st and 2nd picture). This happens while Feature Cache is working. When I zoom out until the point when Feature Cache isn't working anymore polygon appears to be back (3rd picture).

[image]
I tried to install some ArcGIS 10.6.1. patches:

- ArcGIS (Desktop, Engine) 10.6.1 General Update Patch
- ArcGIS (Desktop, Engine) Text Performance Patch
- ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1 Exporting Data From a Layer Patch
- ArcGIS Desktop Dialog Initialization Performance Patch
- ArcGIS Desktop TLS Patch ArcGIS 10.6.1 (Desktop, Engine, Server) Buffering Degenerated Polygon Patch

But none of them helped.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Is there any solution currently available?